# How to parse response to POJO with this response body

Tags: java, json, postman, resttemplate, pojo

New to spring and everything. Trying to hit an endpoint and retrieve the information in the response field. However I don't know how to access information more specific than just bringing back the whole response since it isn't nested in key/values?

I'm using rest template + `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`.
I would like to map the information within response to a pojo, just unsure how to go any further or if I'm even in the right direction here. Example code below.

Postman response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Success",
    "body": {
        "response": "TopStatus=Completed,TopRanking=4 - reqs met, TopDate=2014-04-23,TopTime=11:00 AM,TopEndTime=1:30 AM"
    },
    "status": 200
}
```

Method that is trying to map to Pojo

```
public TopStatus getTopAppStatus(int topId, Status status) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HashMap<String, String> statusObj = new HashMap<String, String>();
    statusObj.put("topStatus", "Fail");
    statusObj.put("topId", "93");

    RestTemplate rt = getRestTemplate();
    URI uri = new URI("urihere");
    HttpEntity<HashMap> entity = new HttpEntity<HashMap>(statusObj, headers);
    TopStatus response = rt.postForObject(uri, entity, TopStatus.class);

    return response;
}
```

Pojo example on how I have it set up

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class TopStatus{

    @JsonProperty("TopStatus")
    private String topStatus;

    rest of fields, setters, getters etc...

}
```

Comment: `@JsonProperty("TopStatus")` isn't going to work. That particular part of the message isn't JSON. The best you can hope for is to extract `response` as a string and then parse it further yourself

Comment: I see. I thought this was the issue but I wasn't sure if I was missing documentation somewhere on how this would be extractable other than pulling out the entire string and doing it myself..

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below code.

```
public TopStatus getTopAppStatus(int topId, Status status) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    TopStatus model = new TopStatus();
    model.setTopStatus("Fail");
    model.setTopId("93");

    RestTemplate rt = getRestTemplate();
    URI uri = new URI("urihere");
    HttpEntity<> entity = new HttpEntity<HashMap>(model, headers);
    TopStatus response = rt.postForObject(uri, entity, TopStatus.class);

    return response;
}
```

Modified Code.

```
public TopStatus getTopAppStatus(int topId, Status status) {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    // Add the Jackson message converter
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    // create request body
    //Here your TopStatus object converted to json. you can use Jackson to do this. 
    String input = "{\"topStatus\":\"Fail\",\"topId\":\"93\"}";


    // set headers
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(input, headers);

    URI uri = new URI("urihere");
    ResponseEntity<TopStatus> response = restTemplate
        .exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, entity, TopStatus.class);

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Why should OP try this code? There is not explanation how will this help or what is a purpose

Comment: I did try it and it's still a null pojo. The pojo has a field called status and it got populated with "200" so that's telling me it's not going within the body to response, etc. My issue is I don't think its possible to extract the response info to map to the pojo with how the response is structured anyways. At least with my current knowledge.

Comment: I normally work with RestClient and NStringEntity. If you wish to chage RestClient I will send you exact code Im using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use postForEntity() method returns ResponseEntity type object instead of 
postForObject()

you need to do small change that will map the response body to the POJO

```
ResponseEntity<TopStatus> response = rt.postForEntity(uri, entity, TopStatus.class);
TopStatus topStatusResponse = response.getBody();
return topStatusResponse;
```

This should return only the expected POJO.

Comment: Seems to still be returning a pojo will all null fields still with that

Comment: can you post the response?